# Run openvpn without root privilegies

Tags: sudo, openvpn

I am working with openvpn, when I type:

```
$ sudo openvpn
```

Every is fine, but when I type:

```
$ openvpn
bash: openvpn: command not found
```

I try in my Debian 8 with [this instructions](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/UnprivilegedUser) but in Jessie I can not find some files, for example: /etc/rc.d/init.d/openvpn-su, etc.

Then, how I run openvpn without root privileges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As openvpn needs root privileges to set routes or ip addresses for an interface it is very uncommon to run it as a user, if possible at all. But the command not found is a simple PATH topic. Check

```
sudo which openvpn
```

where root calls the binary. Normally openvpn lives in /usr/sbin, a location for daemon programs, that are started as root and possible spawn processes as users, such as apache2.

So to call openvpn as a user call

```
 /usr/sbin/openvpn
```

or wherever it lives on your system. Anyway for many things openvpn does it absolutely needs root privileges.